# How to Display a Confirm Dialog on Form Submit with JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui-dialog, confirm

I have following code which works perfectly:

```
   jQuery(function(){
       jQuery('form.register').submit(
          function(){return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form?');
        });
    });
```

It's simply displays a window confirmation with **Yes** or **No** if the user clicks **Yes** the form is submitted if **No** the form is not.

Now I'm trying to achieve the same thing using JQuery UI dialog so I could replace the above as JQuery UI looks better.

My JQuery UI dialog code is as follows:

```
 jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 240,
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 320,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {              
                No: function() {
                    jQuery(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Yes, I Confirm": function() {
                jQuery('form.register').unbind('submit').submit();
                }
            },
            create:function () {
               jQuery(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-button").eq(1).addClass("button-cancel");
               jQuery(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-button").eq(2).addClass("button-primary");
            }

        }); //End dialog
});
```

HTML for JQuery UI dialog.

```
<div id='dialog-confirm' title='Confirm This Form'>
   <p>Once you submit this form there is no turn back.</p>
   <p>Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

Stop form and open JQuery UI dialog.

```
 jQuery('form.register').submit(function(e){
        jQuery("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
        e.preventDefault(e);
  });
```

HTML for Form

```
    <form method="post" action="" class="register">

    <div class="dokan-become-seller">

        <div class="split-row form-row-wide">
            <p class="form-row form-group">
                <label for="first-name">First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="fname" id="first-name" value="" required="required">
            </p>

            <p class="form-row form-group">
                <label for="last-name">Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="lname" id="last-name" value="" required="required">
            </p>
        </div>

        <p class="form-row form-group form-row-wide">
            <label for="company-name">Shop Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="shopname" id="company-name" value="" required="required">
        </p>

        <p class="form-row form-group form-row-wide">
            <label for="seller-url" class="pull-left">Shop URL <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <strong id="url-alart-mgs" class="pull-right"></strong>
            <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="shopurl" id="seller-url" value="ccart3" required="required">
            <small>https://www.example.com/store/<strong id="url-alart"></strong></small>
        </p>

        <p class="form-row form-group form-row-wide">
            <label for="seller-address">Address<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <textarea type="text" id="seller-address" name="address" class="form-control input" required="required"></textarea>
        </p>

        <p class="form-row form-group form-row-wide">
            <label for="shop-phone">Phone Number<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="phone" id="shop-phone" value="" required="required">
        </p>

        
                        <p class="form-row form-group form-row-wide">
                    <input class="tc_check_box" type="checkbox" id="tc_agree" name="tc_agree" required="required">
                    <label style="display: inline" for="tc_agree">I have read and agree to the <a target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com/term-conditions/">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.</label>
                </p>
                    
        <p class="form-row">
        <input type="hidden" id="dokan_nonce" name="dokan_nonce" value="d431d29cf1"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/my-account/account-migration/">            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="20">
            <input type="submit" class="dokan-btn dokan-btn-default" name="dokan_migration" value="Become a Vendor" disabled="disabled">
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I achieve exactly the first method/result without using **e.preventDefault(e);** to stop the form submission with JQuery UI dialog?

The problem I'm experiencing is when the **Yes, I Confirm** is clicked using the JQuery UI dialog. The form attempt to submit but then it just reloads the page and is not submitted. However in the first method when the yes is clicked the form is submitted like normal.

Additional info:

Here is the script which handles the validation and submission of the form.

```
(function($) {

var Dokan_Vendor_Registration = {

    init: function() {
        var form = $('form.register');

        // bind events
        $( '.user-role input[type=radio]', form ).on( 'change', this.showSellerForm );
        $( '.tc_check_box', form ).on( 'click', this.onTOC );
        $( '#shop-phone', form ).keydown( this.ensurePhoneNumber );
        $( '#company-name', form ).on( 'focusout', this.generateSlugFromCompany );

        $( '#seller-url', form ).keydown( this.constrainSlug );
        $( '#seller-url', form ).keyup( this.renderUrl );
        $( '#seller-url', form ).on( 'focusout', this.checkSlugAvailability );

        this.validationLocalized();
        // this.validate(this);
    },

    validate: function(self) {

        $('form.register').validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                var form_group = $(element).closest('.form-group');
                form_group.addClass('has-error').append(error);
            },
            success: function(label, element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    },

    showSellerForm: function() {
        var value = $(this).val();

        if ( value === 'seller') {
            $('.show_if_seller').find( 'input, select' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            $('.show_if_seller').slideDown();

            if ( $( '.tc_check_box' ).length > 0 ) {
                $('button[name=register]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }

        } else {
            $('.show_if_seller').find( 'input, select' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
            $('.show_if_seller').slideUp();

            if ( $( '.tc_check_box' ).length > 0 ) {
                $( 'button[name=register]' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            }
        }
    },

    onTOC: function() {
        var chk_value = $( this ).val();

        if ( $( this ).prop( "checked" ) ) {
            $( 'input[name=register]' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            $( 'button[name=register]' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            $( 'input[name=dokan_migration]' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );
        } else {
            $( 'input[name=register]' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
            $( 'button[name=register]' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
            $( 'input[name=dokan_migration]' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
        }
    },

    ensurePhoneNumber: function(e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 91, 107, 109, 110, 187, 189, 190]) !== -1 ||

            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||

            // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
        }

        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },

    generateSlugFromCompany: function() {
        var value = getSlug( $(this).val() );

        $('#seller-url').val(value);
        $('#url-alart').text( value );
        $('#seller-url').focus();
    },

    constrainSlug: function(e) {
        var text = $(this).val();

        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 91, 109, 110, 173, 189, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
        }

        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 65 || e.keyCode > 90) && (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105) ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },

    checkSlugAvailability: function() {
        var self = $(this),
            data = {
                action : 'shop_url',
                url_slug : self.val(),
                _nonce : dokan.nonce,
            };

        if ( self.val() === '' ) {
            return;
        }

        var row = self.closest('.form-row');
        row.block({ message: null, overlayCSS: { background: '#fff url(' + dokan.ajax_loader + ') no-repeat center', opacity: 0.6 } });

        $.post( dokan.ajaxurl, data, function(resp) {

            if ( resp.success === true ) {
                $('#url-alart').removeClass('text-danger').addClass('text-success');
                $('#url-alart-mgs').removeClass('text-danger').addClass('text-success').text(dokan.seller.available);
            } else {
                $('#url-alart').removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-danger');
                $('#url-alart-mgs').removeClass('text-success').addClass('text-danger').text(dokan.seller.notAvailable);
            }

            row.unblock();

        } );
    },

    renderUrl: function() {
        $('#url-alart').text( $(this).val() );
    },

    validationLocalized: function() {
        var dokan_messages = DokanValidateMsg;

        dokan_messages.maxlength   = $.validator.format( dokan_messages.maxlength_msg );
        dokan_messages.minlength   = $.validator.format( dokan_messages.minlength_msg );
        dokan_messages.rangelength = $.validator.format( dokan_messages.rangelength_msg );
        dokan_messages.range       = $.validator.format( dokan_messages.range_msg );
        dokan_messages.max         = $.validator.format( dokan_messages.max_msg );
        dokan_messages.min         = $.validator.format( dokan_messages.min_msg );

        $.validator.messages = dokan_messages;
    }
};

// boot the class onReady
$(function() {
    Dokan_Vendor_Registration.init();

    $('.show_if_seller').find( 'input, select' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );

    // trigger change if there is an error while registering
    var shouldTrigger = $( '.woocommerce ul' ).hasClass( 'woocommerce-error' ) && ! $( '.show_if_seller' ).is( ':hidden' );

    if ( shouldTrigger ) {
        var form = $('form.register');

        $( '.user-role input[type=radio]', form ).trigger('change');
    }

    // disable migration button if checkbox isn't checked
    if ( $( '.tc_check_box' ).length > 0 ){
        $( 'input[name=dokan_migration]' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
        $( 'input[name=register]' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Nothing looks irregular here. Is there any other submit handler for this form other than what is shown?

Comment: I can't find any action attribute with the form. Where do you want this form submit to?

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the questions to include the script which handles the validation and submission of the form.